# react rendering before database data is retrieved

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm writing an app that pulls my GitHub repos and displays certain information from them (descriptions, etc.).  The app is set up so that if I am not 'initialized' (meaning I haven't sent up an account), then I am forced to the 'CreateAccount' page.  The state of being 'initialized' is held in local storage.  But, if anyone else wants to look at the app, they won't be 'initialized', so I need a second check to see if there is anything in the database (records for each repo).  If so, then the viewer should be 'initialized' and sent to the Home page.  All of this is done in the App component:

```
const App = () => {
   const setupCtx = useContext(SetupContext);
   const devCtx = useContext(DevDataContext);

  // variable to control routing
  let initialized = null;
  
  if (localStorage.getItem("jtsy-signin") === "true") {
    initialized = true;
  } else {
    API.findRepo()
      .then((repo) => {
        console.log('APP found 1 repo', repo)
        if (repo) {
          initialized = true
          localStorage.setItem('jtsy-signin', 'true')
          console.log('1 REPO initialized', initialized)
        } else {
          initialized = false;
        }
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized) {
      console.log('APP useEffect signin=true, redirect to Home page');
      if (localStorage.getItem('jtsy-login') === 'true') {
        setupCtx.updateLoggedIn();
      }
      // console.log('APP devUpdated', setupCtx.state.devUpdated)
      if (setupCtx.state.devUpdated) {
        API.getActiveDevData().then((activeDevData) => {
          // console.log('APP activeDevData', activeDevData.data);
          const developerData = {
            developerLoginName: activeDevData.data.developerLoginName,
            developerGithubID: activeDevData.data.developerGithubID,
            repositories: activeDevData.data.repositories,
            fname: activeDevData.data.fname,
            lname: activeDevData.data.lname,
            email: activeDevData.data.email,
            linkedInLink: activeDevData.data.linkedInLink,
            resumeLink: activeDevData.data.resumeLink,
            active: true
          }
          console.log('APP after DB call', developerData)
          devCtx.updateDev(developerData)
          setupCtx.updateInitialized();
          setupCtx.updateDevUpdated(false)
        })
      }
    };
  }, [setupCtx.state.devUpdated])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            {console.log('IN APP SWITCH initialized', initialized)}
            {initialized ? (
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            ) : (
                <Route exact path="/" component={CreateAccountComp} />
              )}
            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/developer" component={Developer} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginModal} />
            <Route exact path="/logout" component={LogoutModal} />
            <Route exact path="/signin" component={CreateAccountComp} />
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    </div >
  );
};
```

export default App;

The variable 'initialized' controls whether the Home or CreateAccount pages are rendered.  As the code shows, first local storage is checked, and if there is a value there, 'initialized' is set to 'true' and the Home page renders.  This works fine.  But, if there is no value in local storage, I next call findRepo(), which executes a .findOne() in the Mongo database.  Then, the value of 'initialized' is set accordingly.  The delay in getting a response from the database is too long.  If there is no value in local storage, initialized is 'null' when rendering occurs, so the app always goes to the "CreateAccount" page.  I can tell that the database call is responding properly and initialized is getting set to 'true', but it's too late (CreateAccount is already rendered).

I tried putting the database call inside of useEffect, and in a separate useEffect, but neither worked.  I need a better approach to make this work.

Comment: If you want the page to re-render when `initialized` is changed, then it needs to be state. Something like `const [initialized, setInitialized] = React.useState(null)`. Then when you want to update `initialized` you call `setInitialized(true)` or `setInitialized(false)`. This will cause that component to re-render and show what you want.

Comment: Brady - thanks.  I did that, and got caught up in endless re-renders and other infinite looping issues.  I got it working however.

The result is that the app runs slower.  The CreateAccount page appears for a moment before switching to the Home page.  Rendering is delayed.  I was trying to avoid these issues.  It seems that there is a noticeable lag using setState.  That's why I put some information in local storage, which responds faster.

Comment: Could you share your updated code?

Comment: It's here:  https://github.com/frunox/Portfolio

Answer (score 1):

So I have went through your code a little and came up with a solution to add a loading flag to state and use that to render a loading screen if we are waiting on any sort of update.

You could make this loading screen anything you wanted to show when waiting for updates.

Below is the code changes made all in `App.js`

```js
// add isLoading flag to state
const [state, setState] = useState(
  {
     loggedIn: null,
     sync: false,
     initialized: null,
     isLoading: true
  }
)
```

Anytime `setState` is called, update the isLoading flag to true.

```js
// line 55 in App.js
setState({
  ...state,
  initialized: true,
  isLoading: false
})
// line 75
setState({
  ...state,
  initialized: true,
  isLoading: false
})
// line 103
setState({
  ...state,
  initialized: false,
  isLoading: false
})
```

Then the `return` update.

```js
{state.isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
<Route exact path="/" component={state.initialized ? Home : CreateAccountComp} />
```

With these changes the loading screen will show when we are waiting on any sort of update to `initialized`. Then the home screen will once it is updated to true or the create account page will show if it is updated to false.

Comment: Brady - that's was part of my solution.  I now have a 'loading' component!  The problem involves calling the GitHub API, followed by taking some of the data for each repo and storing in the database, then calling getActiveDevData to retrieve the new data and using it to set the context variables.  getActiveDevData is executing before the new values are written in.  I added setTimeout() in the controller file to delay it's execution.  The way the code is written, I can't just append it in a .then block after the API call.  I'll need to improve this.  Thanks for you help.